# ggvis: can't find compute_quantreg function

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm trying to create `geom_quantile`s in `ggvis` and [the documentation](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/layers.html) says that this can be accomplished using

```
geom_quantile = layer_paths + compute_quantreg
```

However, I can't find the `compute_quantreg` function. A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ggvis+compute_quantreg&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) brought nothing up except the same documentation page where it says to do the above. I also tried `??compute_quantreg` as well as `help("compute_quantreg")` with no luck. Any idea where I can find this function?

I'm using the latest version of `ggvis` as of this date (`ggvis_0.4.2`), `dplyr_0.4.3`, and `ggplot2_2.1.0`.

Comment: From the documentation... "However, because ggvis currently provides few transformations, many translations don’t currently exists - but they are on the roadmap and will be added over time."

Comment: I was under the impression that this line applied to those geoms that had no `ggvis` counterpart (e.g. `geom_violin`) but I guess it applies to more than that. Thanks for the info!

Comment: maybe you should self-answer this question? (You can always come back and update your answer later ...) (A reproducible example would also be nice ...) Also: `library(ggvis); apropos("^compute_")` is a good way to see which computational layers (or whatever they're called) *are* implemented ... Also: I would think this might warrant submitting [an issue](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues). Also: https://github.com/ncarchedi/ggcomp/commit/79a2b97d01896620eab16c7372b140f4684afc20

Comment: @Ben, if you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it as the final answer. I think it's much more helpful than what I have right now.

Comment: Feel free to incorporate my comments into your answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [cory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3087927/cory) mentioned in the comments, looks like this function is [on the roadmap but has not yet been added](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/layers.html#conversion-from-ggplot2) as of July 5th 2016.

[Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) also mentioned this neat `apropos` function which can be used as shown below to see which computational layers (or whatever they're called) are implemented.

```
library(ggvis)
apropos("^compute_")
```

---

See [this link](https://github.com/ncarchedi/ggcomp/commit/79a2b97d01896620eab16c7372b140f4684afc20) to the `quantile-compute.R` function for a potential implementation of the `compute_quantile` function.